# TMemo issue on Windows Mobile 6.1

Tags: windows-mobile, freepascal, lazarus, windows-mobile-6

I'm writing a very simple terminal application for Windows Mobile. It opens a serial port, and dumps whatever data is coming into a `TMemo`. The application works just fine on Windows Mobile 5, but on Windows Mobile 6.1, the memo acts strangely. After about 100 characters, no more text is added to the memo and it does not paint itself (e.g. if I open the start menu and close it, the text is not shown anymore). I used this code in a simple application and it reproduced the issue. Any thoughts?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Cick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  while not Application.Terminated do
  begin
    mmPort.Text := mmPort.Text + Chr(Random(90) + 32);
    if Random > 0.9 then
      Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Don't have any Borland products these days, but I'll pitch in: The OLD Project may have had TMemo's `Multiline` property set to True (Multiline is what it is called in Visual Studio). Check the properties for the NEW Project.

Comment: @jp2code `TMemo` doesn't have a `MultiLine` property in Delphi/Lazarus